# Are there scenes in the original theatrical version of Watchmen that are omitted in the ultimate version?

Tags: alternate-version, watchmen

I finally caught up with the Ultimate cut of [Watchmen](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0409459/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0). It is bladder-stressingly long (original theatrical cut: 162 mins; directors cut: 186; ultimate cut 215).

Obviously, there is a lot of extra material in it. But, if memory serves, some of the scenes in the original theatrical release are *missing* or very different. Normally I would expect most material to be extended not cut.

I don't think my memory of the source comic is blending with my memory of the original release. So, am I right that some original scenes are omitted? And, if so, which ones.

Comment: Did you watch any trailers?  Is it possible you're remembering scenes from a trailer that didn't make it into the final movie?

Comment: *"some of the scenes in the original theatrical release are missing or very different"* Can you please mention one or more such scenes that you feel as different among the cuts?